# How find the $\inf\sqrt[r]{n_{1}n_{2}\cdots n_{r}}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, radicals, integers

Let $r,n$ be given positive integers,and $n_{r}$ are positive integers, such
$$n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r}=n$$
find the
$$\inf\sqrt[r]{n_{1}n_{2}\cdots n_{r}}$$

I known use AM-GM $$n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r}\ge r\sqrt[r]{n_{1}n_{2}\cdots n_{r}}$$ so we have  find the sup is 
$$\dfrac{n}{r}?$$

and How to find the inf?

Comment: As $n_i$ need to be integers, $n_i=n/r$ gives you the maximum iff $r \mid n$. Else you will need to look among integers close to $n/r$, in particular when some of the numbers are $\lfloor n/r \rfloor$ and the rest $\lceil n/r \rceil$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>y$, where $\{x,y\}\subset\mathbb N$.

Hence, since $xy\geq(x+1)(y-1)$, we get the minimum for $n_1=n_2=...=n_{r-1}=1$.